# Crash when passing an UnmanagedCallersOnly function pointer to C++ via P/Invoke call decorated with SuppressGCTransition

Tags: c#, function-pointers, c#-9.0

Suppose we have the following C++ code:

```
typedef int (*getIntPtr)(void);

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void InvokeFuncPtr(getIntPtr funcPtr) {
    std::wcout << funcPtr();
}
```

We can match this definition in C#:

```
[DllImport("NativeLib.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl), SuppressGCTransition]
public static unsafe extern void InvokeFuncPtr(delegate* unmanaged[Cdecl]<int> funcPtr);
```

And then we can use this function like so:

```
[UnmanagedCallersOnly(CallConvs = new[] { typeof(CallConvCdecl) })]
public static int ReturnInt() => 123;

// ... Elsewhere:
unsafe {
    InvokeFuncPtr(&ReturnInt);
}
```

---

When `InvokeFuncPtr` is marked with `SuppressGCTransition` this results in the program crashing with the error *"Fatal error. Invalid Program: attempted to call a UnmanagedCallersOnly method from managed code."*. If we remove the `SuppressGCTransition` attribute it works as expected, and `123` is printed to the console.

Is this expected behaviour? I imagine it amounts to the runtime seeing `ReturnInt()` as being invoked from managed code, simply with a couple of extra steps of indirection. If so, is there any way around this, or should I simply leave the `SuppressGCTransition` attribute off?

Comment: [UnmanagedCallersOnly] is exclusively for native code calling C#, [SuppressGCTransition] is exclusively for C# calling native code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should leave off `SuppressGCTransition`, as the stack is what the runtime uses to identify whether the caller is managed or unmanaged.

If there is no transition in the stack, there is no way for the runtime to tell that the stack transitioned to unmanaged.

Alternatively, you can leave off `UnmanagedCallersOnly`, and instead marshal the delegate with `Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate`.